# file_put_contents won't save file

Tags: php, curl

Hi I'm trying to use PHP file_put_contents to save a  raster file to my local drive. The raster file is acquired by curl request, the url link works perfectly fine if open with browser(file is downloadable), but the file_put_contents won't save anything to the folder. Below is my php pseudo code:

```
$ch = curl_init(working_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$save = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents($path_of_file, $save);
```

I have chmod to 777 and have the full write and read to the folder and the save path is correct.

Comment: Please provide the curl result, the url also

Comment: What does `file_put_contents` return? Does `$save` have a value?

Comment: Is the folder you are writing to writable by the web server?

Comment: @gabe3886 yes, i believe so, I chown the folder to www-data:user, I think this is enough?

Comment: @Eknoes I checked the save contentType, it is a tiff format raster file

Comment: @Max_Guo anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Csimpi not sure if you have dealt with spatial data, the file url is a WCS request from my local geoserver: http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=Canada:canada_clay_250_sl1&subset=Long(-99.1237385,-98.5601792)&subset=Lat(50.0633851,50.50594)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have problem with the path or write permissions. I've seen you have cheked it, but you missed something about that. If you have the excepted content in $save variable, it should work. Maybe try with: fwrite($myfile, $txt); What will you get? And maybe is_dir(your path dir) result to debug what is the problem with write.

Comment: @Csimpi yeah.. you would think that's the issue, but I have tried plenty of times. I will keep plugging, now I start to wondering maybe it's my git stage.. anyways I will let you know if I found anything

Comment: Maybe could you print the full path with filename and show it us? Maybe the filename missing from the path?

Comment: ok, I'm therefore assuming that `working_url` is a typo missing the $ for a variable?  Also, what is the value of `$path_of_file`?

Comment: So I have figured out the problem, it was a path issue;  I'm using Javascript in my index.html to ajax information to my php file; executed curl php file, download data and return the location path back to index.html in JSON format. Because my data structure, the path returned back to my index.html is not the right path. Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1):

So I have figured out the problem, it was a path issue;  I'm using Javascript in my index.html to ajax information to my php file; executed curl in php file, download data and return the location path back to index.html in JSON data stream. Because my data structure, the path returned back to my index.html is not the right path(I used "../../filesave". Thanks everyone for helping!

In the future, if anyone had similar issue, be sure to check the save path first and also check to see if have the write and read permission to the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$save = file_get_contents($working_url);
file_put_contents($path_of_file, $save);
```

And please check:

- you can write the destination folder
- you have the right content in $save variable

Maybe provide us the URL to check it.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just did a quick try and it still doesn't work... I have the full permission to the folder, and I double checked the url again this time, still works fine from the browser :/

Comment: Based on the question, it should work, but it don't. There is no another way than try things to find out the solution :)